# Decorator pattern using Java 8

Tags: design-patterns, functional-programming, java-8

Wikipedia has an example of a decorator pattern here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#Second_example_.28coffee_making_scenario.29

I was trying to solve this using functional style using Java 8,the solution I came up:

1.CoffeeDecorator.java

```
public class CoffeeDecorator {

public static Coffee getCoffee(Coffee basicCoffee, Function<Coffee, Coffee>... coffeeIngredients) {

    Function<Coffee, Coffee> chainOfFunctions = Stream.of(coffeeIngredients)
                                                      .reduce(Function.identity(),Function::andThen);
    return chainOfFunctions.apply(basicCoffee);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Coffee simpleCoffee = new SimpleCoffee();
    printInfo(simpleCoffee);

    Coffee coffeeWithMilk = CoffeeDecorator.getCoffee(simpleCoffee, CoffeeIngredientCalculator::withMilk);
    printInfo(coffeeWithMilk);

    Coffee coffeeWithWSprinkle = CoffeeDecorator.getCoffee(coffeeWithMilk,CoffeeIngredientCalculator::withSprinkles);       
    printInfo(coffeeWithWSprinkle);

}

public static void printInfo(Coffee c) {
    System.out.println("Cost: " + c.getCost() + "; Ingredients: " + c.getIngredients());
}
```

}

2.CoffeeIngredientCalculator.java

```
public class CoffeeIngredientCalculator {

public static Coffee withMilk(Coffee coffee) {
    return new Coffee() {

        @Override
        public double getCost() {
            return coffee.getCost() + 0.5;
        }

        @Override
        public String getIngredients() {
            return coffee.getIngredients() + " , Milk";
        }
    };
}

public static Coffee withSprinkles(Coffee coffee) {
    return new Coffee() {

        @Override
        public double getCost() {
            return coffee.getCost() + 0.2;
        }

        @Override
        public String getIngredients() {
            return coffee.getIngredients() + " , Sprinkles";
        }
    };
}
```

}

Now, I am not so convinced with the solution in the CoffeeIngredientCalculator. If we had a single responsibility in the Coffee interface, getCost(), using the functional style and applying the decorator pattern seems a lot better and cleaner. It would basically boil down to a `Function<Double,Double>` ,we would not need the abstract class, separate decorators and can just chain the functions.

But in the coffee example, with 2 behaviors of the cost and description on the Coffee object, I am not so convinced that this is a significant value addition as we are creating an anonymous class,overriding the 2 methods.

Questions:

1) Is this solution acceptable ?

2) If not, is there a better way to solve it using functional style?

3) Should we stick to the usual GOF way of having an abstract class and separate decorator classes in scenarios where the object that we are decorating has multiple methods?

Comment: This seems more like a http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ question.

Answer (score 3):

So, just quick answers:

1. Yes, it's acceptable
2. Though you could decorate / configure the `Coffee` methods independently. Depends on your requirements. Since `Coffee` isn't a functional interface, i.e. has more than 1 method, you have to fall back to the plain old subclassing.
3. No, you don't have to follow GoF literally. They describe more than one alternatives anyway.

Just a final note: If you don't like anonymous classes, then you can write `private static` inner classes, or whatever. One is more compact, the other plays better with garbage collector.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In case of more than 1 method, if we were to still do it the functional way using anonymous classes or private static inner class, is it a better solution than the GoF way ? We did get rid of the Abstract decorator but we are left with the actual decorators(anonymous class/static inner class) which now seem to implement the Coffee interface.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is acceptable.

For practical reasons like single implementation of `equals`, `hashCode`, `toString` I would replace anonymous class with

constructor

```
return new Coffee(coffee.getCost() + 0.2, coffee.getIngredients() + ", Sprinkles");
```

factory method

```
return coffee(coffee.getCost() + 0.2, coffee.getIngredients() + ", Sprinkles");
```

or even copy methods (like in [immutables](http://immutables.github.io/immutable.html#copy-methods))

```
return coffee
    .withCost(coffee.getCost() + 0.2) //new instance
    .withIngredients(coffee.getIngredients() + ", Sprinkles"); //another new instance
```

Comment: The equals,hashCode and toString is  a good point but I am not sure I understand the solution with the constructor/factory method as Coffee is an interface and not a class. Are you referring to instances of decorators which might not be an instance of Coffee ? Could you elaborate on the same ?

Comment: In case of constructor it can be single Coffee class that will hold cost and ingredients. Factory method can still work with interface - it should hide object creation code and provide better code reuse.